# - "used to + infinitive without to" - "ought to + infinitive without to"

Tags: used-to

I am writing to seek clarification on the structure of two specific auxiliaries: "ought" and "used."

1. Modal auxiliary: "ought"
2. Marginal auxiliary: "used"

I have encountered some confusion regarding the following constructions:

- "used + infinitive with to"
- "ought + infinitive with to"

OR

- "used to + infinitive without to"
- "ought to + infinitive without to"

I would greatly appreciate any insights or explanations you can provide to clarify these structures.

Comment: A bit of both! This"use" is always followed by a _to_-infinitival clause, while "ought" is usually (but not always) followed by a _to_-infinitival clause. The bare infinitival is marginal (found mainly in AmE) and occurs in non-affirmative contexts (particularly negatives) as in _Ought we invite them both?_

Comment: If you're asking whether you need the "infinitive marker" ***to*** in contexts like [*"I ought to go now"*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+ought+go%2CI+ought+to+go&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), that linked usage chart should make it clear you really ought o include it. I *very rarely* encounter the bare infinitive after ***ought*** in any text less than a century old, and I've *never* encountered anything like *"We used go fishing on Sundays"* without ***to***.

Comment: @BillJ: This looks like an ELL question to me. Given how uncommon the "bare infinitive" is even in constructions like [*Ought we migrate this to ELL?*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Ought+we+ask%2COught+we+to+ask&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) (AmE only; effectively *non-existent* in BrE), I don't think learners really need to know that it's even a *possibility*.

Comment: You should try and be more specific what your question is. Asking for "any insights or explanations" is far too vague, and will get downvotes and close votes. What do you need to be clarified? Maybe post a sentence you are unsure about.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  That's only because you are in the UK not the US. You shouldna outta been making so many generalizations. :)

Comment: Remember that *use(d) to* has phonemic changes akin to those of *have to*: /ˈjustə/  works like /ˈhæftə/ in devoicing and stress. Notice also how in all the most careful speech, *ought to* is invariably a flapped /ˈɔɾə/ somewhat as though it were *awed a*.

Comment: MW has a decent piece on *used to*. https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/is-it-used-to-or-use-to. I'm reasonably comfortable that *they did use see each other* or *he used go there a lot* are nonstandard. *Ought* is more complicated. But I think the OP wants to know about how to parse the *to* when it does appear.

Comment: @tchrist: It may be that as an American you don't find the lack of ***to*** in *Ought we migrate this to ELL?* so "quaint" as it is to me. But ***ask*** was the best verb I could come up with (NGrams produced *no* infinitives at all](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Ought+we+ask%2COught+we+to+ask&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) when I searched for **Ought we [asterisk] **. So I charted ***ask***, but as you can see from the actual link, (which because of capital ***Ought*** should be very accurate), not using ***to*** is ***very*** unusual.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's not true.  You can't actually trust the casing thing when doing direct searches in google books; they're always case insensitive. I quickly found ten easy examples from the past two decades alone. 2010: [Ought we do X?](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Agriculture_s_Ethical_Horizon/90S1g7TQMxAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22ought+we+do%22&pg=PA216) 2010: ["What ought we do?" I asked.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_Hunger/YkVmgI7YvxkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22ought+we+do%22&pg=PT17)

Comment: @FumbleFingers 2015: [All the Things a Woman Oughtn't Do](https://books.google.com/books?id=MOv5sgEACAAJ&dq=%22oughtn%27t%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUnfTm5_mEAxWHETQIHcWFDqEQ6AF6BAgGEAI). 2014: [Nor ought we see ourselves as merely bright or stupid...](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Me_Myself_and_Us/HOc1bs56wxcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22ought+we+see%22&pg=PA20) There are many, many more of these, and richer ones as well, but it's simply not worth pasting you all the references, since I can fit only two per comment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 2008: [If you ought not do a thing, then a fortiori, you ought not do it in order to bring such and such about. We need to be able to say that a person did a thing correctly though he ought not have done what he did. For what was then the case is that Alex ought not fire the gun on himself. Alice ought not give her child an alpha-pill in order to kill it.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Normativity/bBVPAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22ought+not%22&dq=%22ought+not%22)

Comment: @tchrist: It may well be that *to you,* the lack of an infinitive marker is totally unexceptional. But as [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What+ought+we+to+do%2CWhat+ought+we+do&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) clearly shows, *"What ought we do?"* is very much a minority usage even in AmE (*far* less common in BrE). I can't see why on earth *learners* would want to take the usage on board. I'm sure one could find hundreds of written examples without ***to*** - but by implication, one could just as easily find *thousands* that do include it!

Comment: @FumbleFingers For the simplest reason of all: because there exist native speakers for whom the version with *to* is not grammatical in certain contexts. But this question could not be less clear. What in the world is "used/ought to + infinitive **without** to" supposed to mean? That will hafta be answered before we can continue here.